# No space left on device with encrypted disk that takes all space

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hardware-failure, disk-encryption

I use Ubuntu 11.04. There's no space left on device. I have encrypted the disk that takes up  space (maybe it's good to disable it, but I don't know how).

In shell, I get this message:

> **No space left on device**

I run **df -I**:

```
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1            3055616  602499 2453117   20% /
none                  210161     890  209271    1% /dev
none                  214789       8  214781    1% /dev/shm
none                  214789      53  214736    1% /var/run
none                  214789       3  214786    1% /var/lock
/home/myuser/.Private
                     3055616  602499 2453117   20% /home/myuser df -I
```

Edit:

When I run only **df**:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             48060296  45618928         0 100% /
none                   1538340       684   1537656   1% /dev
none                   1547596       808   1546788   1% /dev/shm
none                   1547596       104   1547492   1% /var/run
none                   1547596         0   1547596   0% /var/lock
/home/myuser/.Private
                      48060296  45618928         0 100% /home/myuser
```

Edit:

I thinking about few solution but I don't know which better and how exactly to do them:

1. to enlarge partition size (I cant install gparted - no more disk space)
2. remove encryption of partition - I really not need that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with the following which directory is taking up space:

```
du -hs /*
```

it will give a list of directories and their sizes in /. Find the directory taking up all the space and fix the issue. Inside the folders you can also use du -hs *

Comment: You can even do it recursively, with `du -h | sort -h`

Comment: `sort -h` will only work with newer versions of gnucoreutils.